# Silverlight Storyboard with multiple ColorAnimations

Tags: c#, .net, silverlight, xaml, storyboard

I'm having a trouble figuring out how to change the fill color of an ellipse along the visible spectrum of colors using ColorAnimation.  ColorAnimation blends the colors together rather than move along the color spectrum, so I came up with the following.

```
<Ellipse x:Name="indicatorEllipse" HorizontalAlignment="Right" VerticalAlignment="Center" Height="20" Width="20" Stroke="Black" Margin="0 0 5 0" >
<Ellipse.Resources>
    <Storyboard x:Name="indicatorStoryboard">
        <!-- Animate the fill color of the Ellipse from red to green over 100 seconds. -->
        <ColorAnimation BeginTime="00:00:00" Storyboard.TargetName="indicatorColorBrush" 
Storyboard.TargetProperty="Color"
From="Red" To="OrangeRed" Duration="0:00:14" />
        <ColorAnimation BeginTime="00:00:15" Storyboard.TargetName="indicatorColorBrush" 
Storyboard.TargetProperty="Color"
From="OrangeRed" To="Orange" Duration="0:00:14" />
        <ColorAnimation BeginTime="00:00:30" Storyboard.TargetName="indicatorColorBrush" 
Storyboard.TargetProperty="Color"
From="Orange" To="Yellow" Duration="0:00:30" />
        <ColorAnimation BeginTime="00:01:01" Storyboard.TargetName="indicatorColorBrush" 
Storyboard.TargetProperty="Color"
From="Yellow" To="YellowGreen" Duration="0:00:14" />
        <ColorAnimation BeginTime="00:01:16" Storyboard.TargetName="indicatorColorBrush" 
Storyboard.TargetProperty="Color"
From="YellowGreen" To="GreenYellow" Duration="0:00:14" />
        <ColorAnimation BeginTime="00:01:31" Storyboard.TargetName="indicatorColorBrush" 
Storyboard.TargetProperty="Color"
From="GreenYellow" To="Green" Duration="0:00:14" />
    </Storyboard>
</Ellipse.Resources>
<Ellipse.Fill>
    <SolidColorBrush x:Name="indicatorColorBrush" Color="Red" />
</Ellipse.Fill>
```

Which doesn't work!  This results in the following error...

> Multiple animations in the same containing Storyboard cannot target
>   the same property on a single element.

Anyone have ideas on how to accomplish this?

Comment: I created multiple storyboards, and added a Completed handler for each storyboard, to switch from one transition to the next, but this can not possibly be the best solution?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames will solve your problem:

```
<ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Color" Storyboard.TargetName="indicatorColorBrush">
    <SplineColorKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:2" Value="OrangeRed"/>
    <SplineColorKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:4" Value="Orange"/>
    <SplineColorKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:6" Value="Yellow"/>
</ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
```

I would also sugest to give Expression Blend a try, it makes working with animations a good deal easier.

Comment: argh!  how did i miss ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames?!  ty!